# Discord.js embedded message error while as far as I know everything is there

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Can someone tell me why I keep getting an error? Says it can't send a empty message when running it.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgzpO.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExSxi.png)

Comment: Which version of discord.js do you have?

Comment: Version 17.7.1 (Newest One)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the node.js version.

Comment: My bad it's V13.6.0

Comment: Do not use images to show your code. Please include your code directly in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is change `message.channel.send(embed)` to `message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })` since when you use `message.channel.send(embed)`, Discord thinks that the variable embed must be a string and tries to send it but it realises that it isn't and therefore the error happens.